# Do a company's sustainability efforts impact employee retention?

Tags: employment, sustainability

It is common to seem claims that sustainable business practices help retain staff:

- A [2019 Fast Company article](https://www.fastcompany.com/90306556/most-millennials-would-take-a-pay-cut-to-work-at-a-sustainable-company) discussed an (unlinked) survey of 1,000 US employees:

  > Nearly 70% of respondents said that if a company had a strong sustainability plan, it would affect their decision to stay with that company long term. More than a third said that they’ve given more time and effort to a job because of their employer’s sustainability agenda. Another 30% said that they’ve left a job in the past because of the company’s lack of a sustainability plan.
- A [Business Leadership Today](https://businessleadershiptoday.com/how-important-sustainability-is-to-employees/) article about a [2016 study](https://www.conecomm.com/research-blog/2016-employee-engagement-study) says:

  > Sustainability is very important to employees and is an important indicator of employee engagement, retention, performance, and well-being. Employees are attracted to companies that focus on sustainability as part of their business strategy because it gives meaning to the work they do.

However, the evidence provided is poor; surveys without a clear methodology.

Is there more direct evidence of impacts to retention (or recruitment, employee satisfaction, or productivity)?

Comment: It seems very difficult to accurately measure this because complex decisions like changing jobs are very rarely monocausal. A lot of things will contribute to the decision of an employee to switch or not switch jobs and measuring the impact of any particular one seems close to impossible.

Comment: I would expect some degree of correlation. A company trying to help saving the environment might be less willing to accept a bullying manager, and that might improve employee retention.